# sp_send_dbmail sending mail even if condition is false - SQL

Tags: sql, select, sendmail

I have an IF statement part of a stored procedure as follows :

```
BEGIN TRY

IF EXISTS (SELECT which I have confirmed returns no results, has a variable called from another table in the where clause)
    BEGIN           
            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                @profile_name   = @dynamic_profile, 
                @recipients     = @dynamic_recipient,
                @subject        = @subjectline,
                @body           = @mailHTML,   
                @body_format    = 'HTML';

    END     
END TRY
```

This is tied to a job that runs every 15mins.
Why is it keep sending me blank emails when the IF statement asks to skip the mail sending if the select returns no results?

My NOCOUNT is set to ON

Comment: There's not much that can be said here without seeing the actual subquery.

Comment: Post your sub query, if you want it to remain private then just call things `table_a`, `table_b`, `field_a`, `field_b`, `table_a.field_b`, `table_b.field_b` etc etc

Comment: Are you sure that SELECT can never return any result, ever? Have you tried attaching a profiling software to your dbms to see what actually gets executed every 15 mins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try - instead:

```
 IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM whatever) > 0
 BEGIN

  --MAIL

 END
```

Comment: why `>1` why not `=1`? besides that will probably not solve the problem or can you explain why an `IF EXISTS` block could be executed if "it"(the result) does not exist (and that same thing will NOT get executed using your code)?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Thank you for pointing that out.  Sort of copy-paste. :)  Where NOCOUNT has not been used and blank result sets are returned, count() will most likely eliminate that false positive.

Comment: Still I do not think that will solve anything, most likely OP's `SELECT` gets called with some unexpected parameters that DO lead to results, how else would this be explainable?

Comment: Well I tried to test it, but cant think of a way to reproduce what OP is claiming. xD

Comment: Thanks guys. IF ... COUNT(*) works but had an ISNULL in my select.. sorry for wasting your time guys!

Comment: As long as we can help :)