# Send an e-mail and stop the execution on condition in SSMS Job

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Every night, we copy some tables from Azure to a server on-premise.
But sometimes, the sources are empty.
To prevent that, we need to add a step in the SSMS Job that control if the tables are empty.
If it is, we would like to send an e-mail and stop the execution.

Here what I have made for now:

```
DECLARE @Result AS TABLE(Query varchar(max));

INSERT INTO @Result
SELECT concat('select ''', TABLE_NAME, ''' as TableName, count(*) as Count from ', TABLE_NAME, ' where Executionid like ','''','%', cast(getdate() as date), 'T%','''') 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_NAME not in ('UPSalesAgreementLineStaging','UpLedgerTransV3Staging','AzureSQLMaintenanceLog','database_firewall_rules');
```

But how to implement this in an SSMS Job to send e-mail and stop the execution ?

Comment: Use `sp_send_dbmail` and an `IF`?

Comment: Thanks, I will try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221202/sp-send-dbmail-sending-mail-even-if-condition-is-false-sql

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

Step 1 : Run a SSIS Job that fill a SQL table.
Step 2 : Run this query :

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX);  
DECLARE @Style  NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';  

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM XXXXX WHERE Counting = 0) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @tableHTML =  
            N'<table border="1">' +
            N'<tr>' +
                    N'<th bgcolor="#F59100"><span style="color: #ffffff">Table Name</span></th>' +
                    N'<th bgcolor="#F59100"><span style="color: #ffffff">Counting</span></th>' +  
            N'</tr>' +  
            CAST((SELECT td= TableName,'', td=Counting
                    FROM XXXXX  
                    WHERE Counting = 0  
                    FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'</table>' ;
        
        SELECT @tableHTML
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
        @profile_name = 'XXXXXX',  
        @recipients = 'xxxxx@xxxx.com' ,
        @body = @tableHTML,  
        @subject = 'Alert',
        @body_format = 'HTML';

        THROW 51000, 'Process Is Not Finished', 1
    END
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).